# param is missing or the value is empty: company

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I am trying to get this API working but have come to this error which i don't know how to solve.I am getting the error on title.I used postman extension from google chrome.And tried to do a post request on

```
localhost:3000/companies
```

and got an error. Which looks like this below

> ActionController::ParameterMissing in `CompaniesController#create`
>       param is missing or the value is empty: company
>
> ```
> def company_params
>  (this line is highlighted) params.require(:company).permit(:name, :phone, :email, :website, :address, :customer_id, :additional_info)
> end
> end
>    Request
>
> Parameters:
>
> {"name"=>"harun"}
> ```

I have generated a `rails-api`, added `avtive_model_serializer` and `rack-cors gem`. Modified `config/application` for cors.

And then generated a scaffold for company.

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.0'
gem 'rack-cors'
```

**config/application.rb**

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
  end
end
```

**app/serializers/company_serializer.rb**

```
class CompanySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
 attributes :id, :name, :phone, :email, :website, :address, :customer_id, :additional_info
end
```

**controllers/companies_controller.rb**

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_company, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
  def index
    @companies = Company.all
    render json: @companies
  end

  def show
    render json: @company
  end

  def create
    @company = Company.new(company_params)
    if @company.save
      render json: @company, status: :created, location: @company
    else
      render json: @company.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def update
    @company = Company.find(params[:id])

    if @company.update(company_params)
      head :no_content
    else
      render json: @company.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @company.destroy

    head :no_content
  end

  private

    def set_company
      @company = Company.find(params[:id])
    end

    def company_params
      params.require(:company).permit(:name, :phone, :email, :website, :address, :customer_id, :additional_info)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the parameters `{"name"=>"harun"}` you need to pass `{"company" => { "name"=>"harun"} }`.

In postman (if you are sending json data) send this data:

```
{"company":{"name":"harun"}}
```

If you are sending form data send this:

```
company[name] = "harun"
```

With strong parameters, and error is risen when the required parameter is not found:

```
params.require(:company)
```

Comment: Yes.THANKS A TON. i did company[name] and it worked.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Your request parameters need to be like the following :

```
{
    company: {
        name: 'ABC'
    }
}
```

You have specified in your company_params function, require(:company) which means it will look for company key in your params.

Which in Postman is - 
company[name] : ABC

Comment: THANK YOU for showing the correct way of it.I have done company[name] and it solved it. :) Thank you a TON for your help